# ReBus: Unable to use sagas with handlers decorator

Tags: decorator, rebus, saga

I use Rebus 3.0.1 with Simpleinjector. I have registered a decorator, for logging, of all the handlers, this way:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IHandleMessages<>), typeof(HandlerLogDecorator<>));
```

Everything works fine, except the Sagas: because, in **LoadSagaDataStep**, the following code

```
            var handlerInvokersForSagas = context.Load<HandlerInvokers>()
            .Where(l => l.HasSaga)
            .ToList();
```

is not able to find the Saga under the covers.
If I unregister the decorators, saga starts working again.

Any suggestion to conciliate sagas and handlers decorators?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as you have discovered, Rebus does not expect handlers (including sagas) to be wrapped in decorators.

It uses decorators a lot for various things internally, and it encourages the use of decorators as an extension point for developers, but that only goes for all of Rebus' services like `IPipeline`, `ISubscriptionStorage`, etc.

If you want to log stuff in relation to message handling, a better extension point would be to either

a) use [`Rebus.Events`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.Events) and simply install an event handler like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Events(e => {
        e.AfterMessageHandled += (bus, headers, message, context, args) => {
            // log stuff in here :)
        };
    })
    .Start();
```

or

b) create an incoming pipeline step that logs what you want to log like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => {
        o.Decorate<IPipeline>(c => {
            var step = new YourLoggingStep();
            var pipeline = c.Get<IPipeline>();

            return new PipelineStepInjector(pipeline)
                .OnReceive(step, PipelineRelativePosition.After, typeof(DeserializeIncomingMessageStep));
        });
    })
    .Start();
```

probably wrapping all of the ugly stuff in an extension method that makes usage look more like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => {
        o.LogHandledMessages();
    })
    .Start();
```

Comment: Sorry I thought the answer solved the problem but it does not.
Now that I was going to put my hands on it, I noticed that decorating the pipeline is not the same as decorating the handlers. In fact, you can not decorate the single execution of `await invoker.Invoke ();` but the execution of the list of `HandlerInvokers` (what Rebus already does).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Extrema ratio would be to replace `DispatchIncomingMessageStep` in the pipeline, but I dislike it because `DispatchIncomingMessageStep` is a core part of the framework.